# display:inline-block; and display:none; Not working for replacing text with hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I've been working on a little site full of games for mere convenience, and I have tried to put a little message to appear when the mouse is hovering over the links. My code for the html looks like this in html:

```
<li><a href="game1.html"><span class="games">Text normally</span><span class="hovergames">Text displayed on hover.</span></a></li>
```

And in style.css the code is as follows:

```
.hovergames{background-color:#242423; a:hover.games{display:none;} a:hover.hovergames{display:inline-block;} a.hovergames{display:none;}
```

My goal is trying to get "text displayed on hover" to appear on hover instead of "text normally" and this is not working. Is there something I can do so the text doesn't end up displaying both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.hovergames {
  display: none;
}

a:hover .hovergames {
  display: block;
}

a:hover .games {
  display: none;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="game1.html"><span class="games">Text normally</span><span class="hovergames">Text displayed on hover.</span></a></li>
```